# Pagination in PHP blog

Tags: php, pagination

I am creating a blog in PHP (trying to keep it close to OOP) and am struggling with getting pagination to work on the page that displays all posts.

The code for the blog.php in question is

```
<?php
require_once("includes/init.php");
$pagetitle = "Blog";
//include header.
require_once("includes/template/header.php");
// initialise script
$blog = new Blog($db);
$parsedown = new Parsedown();
// load blog posts
$posts = $blog->get_posts();
?>

<div class="container">

    <div class="row">

        <div class="col-lg-12">
            <h1 class="page-header">Blog Home</h1>
        </div>

    </div>

    <div class="row">

        <div class="col-lg-8">
            <?php foreach ($posts as $post) { ?>
                <h1><a href="<?php echo $post['slug']; ?>"><?php echo $post['title']; ?></a>
                </h1>
                <p class="lead">by <a href="#"><?php echo $post['author']; ?></a>
                </p>
                <hr>
                <p><i class="fa fa-clock-o"></i> Posted on <?php echo date("d/m/Y", strtotime($post['date'])); ?> At <?php echo date("H:i", strtotime($post['date'])); ?> in <?php 
                $categories = $blog->get_categories($post['id']); 
                $links = array(); 
                foreach ($categories as $category) { 
                    $links[] = "<a href='blog-categories.php?id=".$category['category_slug']. "'>".$category['category_name']."</a>"; 
                }
                echo implode(", ", $links); ?></p>
                <hr>
                <p><?php $content = $parsedown->parse($post['content']); echo substr($content,0,445) ; ?></p>
                <a class="btn btn-primary" href="<?php echo $post['slug']; ?>">Read More <i class="fa fa-angle-right"></i></a>
                <a class="btn btn-primary" href="<?php echo $post['slug']; ?>#disqus_thread"><i class="fa fa-angle-right"></i></a>

                <hr>
            <?php }
                ?>

        </div>
```

What can I add either to the Blog class or put in a new class to allow blog.php to only show the first 5 results and then give a 'next' link to view the next set of 5? I'm not worried about displaying the total number of pages.

As the class is very large, it can be viewed at http://pastebin.com/qN5ii2Ta.

Comment: You are not showing the class in question, nor are you showing any attempt at pagination in your code. Specifically, where are you having a problem implementing pagination?

Comment: I have made several attempts at pagination using advice from here and other sites, however none of them seem to actually work with my code, hence why asking here.  post updated with link to class.

Comment: this can help you out http://www.phpeasystep.com/phptu/29.html

Comment: You need to post pertinent code in your question, not in an external link.  Please include pertinent parts of your class here.  Also, the class referenced does not show any attempt at pagination.  Please show what you have done, so others can help give advice on your problem.

Answer (score 1):

You are currently using a method get_posts(). You could redefine this method to accept a starting point to begin gathering posts from. With this starting point defined you can LIMIT how many posts are returned in your SQL query.